# Why do we care about transposes/duals of linear maps?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

I'm just starting to go deeper in my linear algebra education, and this question: [Why do we care about dual spaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3749/why-do-we-care-about-dual-spaces) helped my intuition and motivation immensely, especially Matt E's answer.

So, I'm curious if that kind of explanation can be furthered to transposes/duals of linear maps? (Or of course, any kind of explanation that could enlighten me!)

Answer (score 3):

If you seek elegant and powerful examples of applications of linear functionals, duality, adjoints etc. then all that and more can be found in [Umbral Calculus.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus) You can find a nice introduction in Steven Roman's book [The Umbral Calculus.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486441393)  These few fundamental ideas serve to explain, unify and organize many hundreds of diverse properties of special functions that arise in combinatorics.

Comment: Also see: http://romanpress.com/MathArticles/MathArticles.htm