# An identity involving Catalan numbers and binomial coefficients.

Tags: combinatorics, summation, catalan-numbers

I stumbled upon the following identity
$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kC_k\binom{k+2}{n-k}=0\qquad n\ge2$$
where $C_n$ is the $n$th Catalan number. Any suggestions on how to prove it are welcome!

This came up as a special case of a generating function for labeled binary trees. Actually I can directly prove the identity is zero by showing that certain trees don't exist, but I expect that seeing a direct proof will help me find nice closed formulae for other coefficients of the generating function.

Comment: What attempts have you made? Can you provide any context for the question?

Comment: @AlanAbraham it came up as a special case of a generating function for labeled binary trees. Actually I can directly prove the identity is zero by showing that certain trees don't exist, but I expect that seeing a direct proof will help me find nice closed formulae for other coefficients of the generating function.

Comment: I tried finding a generating function $f_d(x)$, whose coefficient of $x^n$ is $\binom{d-n+2}{n}$. I did get an explicit formula from the recursion $f_d(x)=f_{d-1}(x)+xf_{d-2}(x)$, but it turned out to be really disgusting, and the coefficient of $x^d$ in $c(x)f_d(x)$ does not seem feasible to obtain from there. I don't think this method would be viable.

Comment: Interesting result. Given $\,c_0,c_1\,$ define $\,c_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{n+k+1} {n+2 \choose n-k}c_k\, $ for $\,n>1.\,$ Then $\,c_n = a_nc_0 + b_nc_1\,$ where $\,a_n = 2C_n - C_{n+1} = A099376(n-1)\,$ and $\,b_n = C_{n+1} - C_n = A000245(n).$

Comment: See [How to prove $\sum_{s=0}^{m}{2s\choose s}{s\choose m-s}\frac{(-1)^s}{s+1}=(-1)^m$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1559612/471884) and [Calculate $\sum_{0 \le k } \binom{n+k}{2k} \binom{2k}{k} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3174979/471884) for related

Comment: Please include your comments in the body of question. It helps a lot if the right context is provided in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My answer uses the same methods as that of [tc2718](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1560084)'s answer to a very similar problem.

Let $a_n$ be the quantity in question, and let $F(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n$. We will evaluate $F$ by switching the order of summation, applying the binomial theorem to the inner sum, rearranging a bit, and then recognizing the expression as the Catalan generating function evaluated at $-x-x^2$.
$$
\begin{align}
F(x)
  &=\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k C_k \binom{k+2}{n-k}x^n
\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k C_k  \sum_{n= k}^\infty\binom{k+2}{n-k}x^n
\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k C_k \; x^k(1+x)^{k+2}
\\&=(1+x)^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty C_k \; (-x-x^2)^k
\\&=(1+x)^2 \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4(-x-x^2)}}{2(-x-x^2)}
\\&=(1+x)^2 \frac{1-\sqrt{(1+2x)^2}}{2(-x-x^2)}
\end{align}
$$
Here, we must choose the branch of $\;\sqrt{\cdot}\;$ where $\sqrt{(1+2x)^2}=+(1+2x)$, since the other choice causes a pole at $x=0$, and our definition of $F(x)$ makes it clear there is no pole there. Finally,
\begin{align}
F(x)=(1+x)^2 \cdot \frac{1-(1+2x)}{-2x(1+x)}=1+x
\end{align}

This closed form expression for $F(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n$ shows that $a_0=a_1=1$, while $a_n=0$ for $n\ge 2$.

Answer (score 5):

This answer uses Umbral calculus.

Given the formal variable $\,c,\,$ define the formal
power series linear operator

$$ L\!\!\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nc^n\right] :=
  \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nC_n. $$

Define the Catalan number generating function

$$ C(x) := L\left[\frac1{1-c\,x}\right] =
 \sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^n = 
 \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}.  $$

Define the generating function

$$ F(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty
  (-1)^kC_k\binom{k+2}{n-k}x^n. $$

Define the generating function

$$ f(x,y) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \left(\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{k+2\choose n-k}y^k\right)x^n. $$

Now, by previous definitions

$$ F(x) = L[f(x,c)]. $$

Verify that

$$ f(x,y) = \frac{(1 + x)^2}{ 1 + y (x + x^2) }. $$

Now get

$$  F(x) = (1+x)^2 C(-(x+x^2)) = 1+x $$

from

$$ C(-(x\!+\!x^2)) \!=\!
 \frac{1\!-\!\sqrt{1\!+\!4(x\!+\!x^2)}}
{-2(x\!+\!x^2)} \!=\! \frac{1-(1\!+\!2x)}{-2(x\!+\!x^2)} \!=\! \frac1{1\!+\!x}. $$

---

Notice, my answer to
[MSE question 4317353](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317353)
also uses Umbral calculus to prove another Catalan number recursion
identity. Also, the accepted answer to this question is very similar to
mine except it does not use the Umbral calculus linear operator.

Comment: (+1) Extremely slick! As a quick question, I'm familiar with the umbral calculus, but not particularly _comfortable_ with it. Do you have any insight as to which problems are amenable to the technique, and do you know of any resources for practicing? Ideally there would be something like _Generatingfunctionology_ but for the umbral calculus, though I know that's a high bar to clear!

Comment: @HallaSurvivor That is a good question! Please ask this as a question here on MSE and you may get good answers for it.

Comment: I'd be happy to ^_^

Comment: If you have some time to chime in, I've asked the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4333769/intuition-for-when-a-problem-may-be-amenable-to-the-umbral-calculus)

Comment: Cool. This looks like a very powerful technique which I look forward to diving into further!

Comment: @HallaSurvivor The book by Roman [cited here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/203046/242) is a nice introduction to Umbral Calculus. It includes many illuminating examples and is highly accessible.