# Specific element of the dual space of $\ell^1$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Denote the dual of $\ell^1$ as $(\ell^1)^*$.  I have learned that $(\ell^1)^* = \ell^\infty$.  I am trying to better understand this statement.  I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3749/why-do-we-care-about-dual-spaces) question to be helpful, but a question still remains.

For concreteness, $\ell^1$ is the set of all functions $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ such that $\sum_{i \in \mathscr{N}} |f(i)| <\infty$ and $\ell^\infty$ is the set of all functions $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ such that $\sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |(i)| <\infty$.  In other words, $\ell^1$  is the set of absolutely convergent sequences, where $\ell^\infty$  is the set of sequences where each element is bounded.

Consider a sequence of scalars $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=0}^\infty$, such that $\sup_i|a_i| < \infty$.  Then, for $f=(f_1, f_2,...) \in \ell^1$, define $T$ as $Tf = \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} a_if_i$.  Noting that $\| Tf \| \leq \|a\| \|T\| $, $T$ is clearly a bounded linear functional on $\ell^1$ and hence it is in $(\ell^1)^*$.

The set equality above must mean that if $T \in (\ell^1)^*$, then  $T \in \ell^\infty$. But how could this be? Every element of $\ell^\infty$ is a function from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$.  $T$ is a function $\ell^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$. They just seem fundamentally different.

I am clearly missing something obvious--and I suspect it is related to the fact that I defined the $T$ by using a sequence.  Perhaps the equality is saying something about this sequence?

Comment: In fact the spaces $(\ell^1)^*$ and $\ell^\infty$ are not equal but isomorphic.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net so the equality does not mean set equality, but rather that there exists some isomorphism?  So what can I say about that specific $T$ I defined above?  That there is some isometric function that takes it to a corresponding element in $\ell^\infty$?  Is that the meaning of saying they are isomorphic?

Comment: The idea is that the mapping $\ell^\infty\to(\ell^1)^*$ given by $\{a_i\}\mapsto T$ is an isometric isomorphism onto $(\ell^1)^*$.

Comment: @Aweygan that is helpful.  However, for $g=(a_1,a_2,...) \in \ell^\infty$ as above, $\|g\| = \sup_i a_i$.  On the other hand, if $T \in (\ell^1)^*$ is defined such that for $f=(f1,f2,...)\in \ell^1$, $Tf = \sum a_i f_i$, then $\|T\| = \sum_i |a_i|$, which is not in general equal to $\|g\|$, and so $\{a_i\} \rightarrow T$ is not an isometric isomorphism, right?  So, perhaps $T$ should instead be defined as $T = \sup_i\{a_i  f_i\}$?

Comment: I guess I am just trying to understand, what is the $T\in (\ell^1)^*$ that corresponds to $\{a_i\} \in \ell^\infty$?